# Can't send messages to MSMQ private queue remotely from asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, msmq

I am trying to send messages from my asp.net mvc application to a remote private queue, and I am getting this exeption..

```
The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.
```

here is my code...

```
 using (var messageQueue = new 
        MessageQueue(@"FormatName:Direct=OS:ComputerName\private$\testing"))
        {
            var message = new Message
            {
                Body = "just testing"
            };
            messageQueue.Label = "Message header";
            try
            {
                messageQueue.Send(message, "Title");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

I have seen similar questions on SO but none of them solved my problem.

Additional notes:

1. The MSMQ is installed on my PC in worker group mode (don't know if that makes 
   a difference, just thought you ought to know)
2. The queue is a non transactional queue.

Comment: Im guessing the name of the computer on the LAN isn't ComputerName?

Comment: @LDJ I Triple checked. I actually copied the path out of the properties of the queue.

Comment: So dont you need to use FormatName:Direct=OS:<<ACTUALNAMEOFMACHINE>>\private$\testing?

Comment: @LDJ  of course that's what I am doing I just changed it for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here I am answering my own question. I solved the problem to changing from

`MessageQueue(@"FormatName:Direct=OS:ComputerName\private$\testing"))` 
to ...

`MessageQueue("FormatName:DIRECT=OS:ComputerName\\private$\\testing"))`